# gmail reply-to references not showing

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm having trouble to reply to an email using API. I follow the instructions and the message does in fact have the same threadId but somehow I'm not getting the correct references.
In the code section you can find an example of request I sent.

Code
`From: From Name from_email@gmail.com

To: To Name to_email@gmail.com

Subject: Re: test subject

References: message_id@mail.gmail.com message_id@mail.gmail.com

In-Reply-To: message_id@mail.gmail.com

Reply message test 1
`

Output
Message has the same thread ID as the this one message_id@mail.gmail.com. I can't see the email references in the Ui (three dots). (You can see the screenshot attached)

Steps
Send a reply to a message using API
See the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lpap.jpg)